# Is this a bug or feature of Svelte two-way bindings?

Tags: svelte

Please someone explain this behavior of Svelte two-way bindings to me.

App.svelte:

```
    <script>
        import Child from './Child.svelte';
    
        const dataTemplate = {dataKey: [1,2,3], dataValue: ['1','2','3']};
    
        //  let data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(dataTemplate));   --->   Not matter
        let data = {dataKey: [1,2,3], dataValue: ['1','2','3']};
    
        //  let dataNew = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(dataTemplate));   --->   Not matter
        let dataNew = {dataKey: [1,2,3], dataValue: ['1','2','3']};

    </script>

    <Child
        bind:data={data.dataKey}
        bind:dataNew={dataNew.dataKey}  
    />
```

Child.svelte:

```
    <script>

        export let data;
        export let dataNew;
    
        $: if (data) {
            console.log('--- WTF?---');
        
    
        $: if (data) {
            console.log('--- WTF-Trigger---');
            dataNew = [{key: 1, val: '1'}];
       }

    </script>

    <button on:click={()=>{console.log('Clicked');dataNew=dataNew}}>
        Click me
    </button>
```

REPL: [This question Svelte REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/72c2a22de21643899e958449b74cf790?version=3.49.0)

I've been dealing with this problem for more than a day, but I can't figure it out...
Is this a bug or is this a feature of Svelte two-way bindings? The data of "data" not changed, why "data" (---WTF?---) have been triggered in Child.svelte component?

Comment: because you are doing `if (data)`

Comment: on mount (load) of course, but same behaviour on button click

Comment: because you are changing the biding

Comment: there are two separate bindings intentionally

Comment: Why not reduce the code some more to better see what's going on https://svelte.dev/repl/315dcef31b8646aca671a147afcbc2c6?version=3.49.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reactive statements trigger on invalidation of `data` because that is part of its `if` condition.

Because the second reactive statement *uses* both `data` and `dataNew`, Svelte appears to invalidate `data` as well when `dataNew` is changed. This has nothing to do with two-way binding (`bind:`) and happens without it, too.

Relevant compiled output:

```js
const click_handler = () => {
    console.log('Clicked');
    ($$invalidate(0, dataNew), $$invalidate(1, data));
};

// Reactive statements
$$self.$$.update = () => {
    // ...
    if ($$self.$$.dirty & /*data*/ 2) {
        $: if (data) {
            console.log('--- WTF-Trigger---');
            $$invalidate(0, dataNew = [{ key: 1, val: '1' }]);
        }
    }
};
```

To me this looks like a bug because `dataNew` is not being read in the second reactive statement and there should be no reason to invalidate `data` other than to trigger the reactive statement which has that as its necessary condition (`$$self.$$.dirty & /*data*/ 2`).

---

The change that both properties get invalidated was apparently introduced between Svelte version 3.2.0 and 3.3.0. [In 3.2.0](https://svelte.dev/repl/72c2a22de21643899e958449b74cf790?version=3.2.0) the click handler only invalidates `dataNew` and the reactive statements are not called.

```js
function click_handler() {console.log('Clicked');$$invalidate('dataNew', dataNew)}

$$self.$$.update = ($$dirty = { data: 1 }) => {
    // ...
    if ($$dirty.data) { if (data) {
            console.log('--- WTF-Trigger---');
            $$invalidate('dataNew', dataNew = [{key: 1, val: '1'}]);
        } }
};
```

Comment: It seems that this only happens when passing (binding) a non primitive values (objects, arrays). How do you think this can be avoided?

Comment: 1. I would not rely on reactive statements being called a specific number of times, they should represent logical invariants. 2. This should probably be reported in the Svelte repository as a potential bug; if it is, it might be fixed anyway.

Answer (score 0):

It should be noted that moving the trigger reason into a separate function solves the problem.

App.svelte:

```
<script>
    import Child from './Child.svelte';
    
    let data = {};  
    let dataNew = {};
</script>

<Child
    bind:data
    bind:dataNew
/>
```

Child.svelte:

```
<script>
    export let data;
    export let dataNew;
    
    const updateDataNew = () => {
        dataNew = {};
    }
    
    $: if (data) {
        console.log('--- WTF? ---');
    }
    
    $: if (data) {
        console.log('--- WTF Trigger ---');
        updateDataNew();
        // dataNew = {};
    }

</script>

<button on:click={()=>{console.log('Clicked');dataNew=dataNew}}>
    Click me
</button>
```

REPL: [This answer Svelte REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/270378c92a03464584215ab12d131465?version=3.49.0)