# Trying to understand why changing a variable re-triggers reactive statements of unrelated variables

Tags: svelte, svelte-3

## Context

Here's a simplified version of my context:

[image: context]
I have a component which

- fetches a collection of items from the server  -> `bookmarks [{title, url}, ...]`
- in a reactive statement, populates a new collection from `bookmarks` by adding a new property with the domain name of the url: `xbookmarks = [{title, url, domain}, ...]
- makes it possible to filter bookmarks by domain, by displaying a list of checkboxes, one per domain:

  - this is achieved by declaring a `filter: {domains: {domain:true|false, ...}}` variable
  - the `filter.domains` map is populated in a reactive statement by iterating over `xbookmarks` and setting all domains to `true`
  - finally, a `filterdBookmarks` variable is computed in a reactive statement by filtering `xbookmarks` using `filter`
- displays the filtered bookmarks

## What I have tried

Here's the flow in pseudo-javascript:

```js
let bookmarks=[]

let xbookmarks=[]
$: xbookmarks = bookmarks.map(b=>{...b, domain: computeDomain(b)})

let filter = {domains: {}}
$: filter.domains=extractDomains(xbookmarks)

let filterdBookmarks=[]
$: filterBookmarks = xbookmarks.filter(using filter)
```

Here's a link to the svelte REPL with the complete code described above: https://svelte.dev/repl/d07ffc88e4a34cb797d2ceb6ba0ec6a4?version=3.49.0

## Problem

When I try to uncheck one of the domains checkboxes:

### Expected behaviour:

`filter` changed => trigger recomputation of depending variables, i.e. `filterdBookmarks`

### Actual behaviour:

`filter` changed => Svelte recomputes `xbookmarks`, then `filter.domains` which resets it back to all domains being checked, then `filterdBookmarks`

I can't understand why Svelte considers that `xbookmarks` depends on `filter`

When I looked into the JS code generated by Svelte, this shouldn't be happening:

[image: dependency graph]

As can be seen in the screenshot above, the generated code matches my intuition about the dependencies:

1. `xbookmarks` is recomputed when `bookmarks` changes
2. `filter.domains` is recomputed when `xbookmarks` changes
3. `filteredBookmarks` is recomputed when either of `filter` of `xbookmarks` changes

P.S.: I have just started learning and playing with Svelte

Comment: @H.B.: that indeed seems to be the case !
Thank you !

Could you post your comment as an answer so that I could accept it ?

Comment: Well, technically this probably should be closed as duplicate or deleted, but ok...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably a bug. The `input_change_handler` invalidates too many variables.

This worked in [v.3.2.0](https://svelte.dev/repl/d07ffc88e4a34cb797d2ceb6ba0ec6a4?version=3.2.0), see also [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73204149/546730) and [issue opened for it](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues/7749).